# Advice on Testing a sql connection and swapping databases

Tags: c#, sql, sqlconnection

Hello everyone i was hopping to get a little advice on how someone would go about doing something

1. i need to test sql connection for a main server, if the connection returns false then i need to set a variable that will tell the program to use it own local sql ce database

how would yall go about testing that connection then setting that variable?

Would yall agree on something like this

```
try
{
  con.open();
  standalone=false;
  con.close();
}
catch
{
 standalone=true;
 con.close();
}
```

Comment: How do you connect to your database? What technology do you use? ADO.NET or something else?

Comment: @Christos Paisios  sorry my bad for not mentioning it, i connect to a sql2008 r2 server, i connect using a connection string using con.open(); my internal db is a sql ce db with the same tables i have a good ideal how to swap to them, but not sure how i can check the connection and when it fails then swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution, but if you have a bunch of queries would be ok. Whenever you need to open a connection to your object you check if everything is ok with your first connection string. Otherwise your second conneciton string.

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
{
    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        // Here goes your statements for querying your db.

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        using(SqlConnection Conn2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
        {
            try
            {
                 Conn2.Open();
                 // Here goes your statements for querying your db.
            }
            catch(Exception Ex2)
            {
                 // Here goes your error handling code for the second connection
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although the above might be a solution to your problem, I should state a concern, which have arisen since I read your question. Suppose you connect to your first database and you do any tranasction you need with it. After a little time there comes a problem and you cannot connect to your first db. So you will connect to your second db. Then the data of the second db will be incosistent with the data you had, when you were using the first db.

Comment: Nice Response, I do have a crap ton of queries would you suggest adding the additonal db into each catch or running what i had on a timer to set the var to tell it what to do, only reason i ask, as i like your method and i know in doing it, it would automatically use the main when it came back online there are certain feature i dont want them to be able to do until it is back online

Comment: right now in those feature it looks at a var that is set to 1 or 0, wether or not it will pop up a form for them to make changes

Comment: Sorry just read your Comment, This is also a promblem yes, i have been thinking about a nightly procedure that keeps that db up to date as well as a way for the customer to update there db manually, another thing i was thinking was to run this procedure when they make a change in the system to keep the others updated, that is next on my to do list if you have any input on how to check changes in a db that would be a help lol

Comment: Since you have a crap ton of queries, the above approach would be definitely a headache. The only way to tackle with this problem and build a far better architecture to your project, it would be to try to implement the repository pattern. Please look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-2cplusdoneplusright. Then you will have in one place all your data access code and there you could implement the above, without needing to replicate in a hundreds or more places in your code. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: However, I forgot to mention that If you haven't before got engaged with this pattern, it will take you a bit of time to learn it. It is nothing difficult, but worth every millisecond of study, because after understanding it, you can use it in all your projects making them more maintanable.

Comment: Thanks Christos for the info ill holor if i have any questions, now that i look at it yourmethod would work fine, i only have one instance where i am not using the local db, and i could use the above code without replicating it 100 times so i will do so and test it, i will read what is in codeproject as i am a learning junkie lol, and after this i am off to figure out how to keep the tables up to date lol

Comment: Allright, wish you good luck ! If you need any help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle sqlexception and if one occurs you can then use your local connection
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer i understand what your saying, but how would you go about checking would you have a timer checking connection the swapping to a local db or have code to swap to a local after each instance of a con.open in the program